# Site.createPortalUser is overriding account owner

Tags: apex, community

I'm customizing the selfRegister function for a community and am running into the 'Account Owner must have a role' error.  The problem is, the account I'm passing into the function has an owner with a role, but the Owner keeps getting overwritten back to the community guest user who can't have a role

This is the function creating the user and I also have a trigger setting the owner of the account to the same user, but when I query for the account, the owner is still the community guest user.

```
global static String selfRegister(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String confirmPassword,
                                  string strAddress, String startUrl) {
    system.debug('IN THE SELF REGISTER FUNCITON');
    system.debug(password);
    system.debug(confirmPassword);
    Savepoint sp = null;
    try {
        sp = Database.setSavepoint();

        if (lastName == null || String.isEmpty(lastName)) {
            return Label.Site.lastname_is_required;
        }

        if (email == null || String.isEmpty(email)) {
            return Label.Site.email_is_required;
        }

        User u = new User();
        u.Username = email;
        u.put('Email',email);

        u.FirstName = firstName;
        u.LastName = lastName;


        AddressWrapper address = (AddressWrapper) JSON.deserializeStrict(strAddress, AddressWrapper.class);

        String networkId = Network.getNetworkId();

        // If using site to host the community the user should not hit s1 after logging in from mobile.
        if (networkId != null && siteAsContainerEnabled(Network.getLoginUrl(networkId))) {
            u.put('UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI',true);
        }

        String nickname = ((firstName != null && firstName.length() > 0) ? firstName.substring(0,1) : '' ) + lastName.substring(0,1);
        nickname += String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger()).substring(1,7);
        u.put('CommunityNickname', nickname);


        if (!isValidPassword(password, confirmPassword)) {
            return Label.site.passwords_dont_match;
        }
        validatePassword(u, password, confirmPassword);

        Contact con = new Contact(
                FirstName = firstName,
                LastName = lastName,
                Email = email,
                MailingStreet = address.street,
                MailingCity = address.city,
                MailingState = address.state,
                MailingPostalCode = address.zip,
                MailingCountry = address.country
        );

        insert con;


        Contact newCon =
                [SELECT Id, AccountId
                FROM Contact
                WHERE Id = :con.Id];

        Account acc =
                [SELECT Id, OwnerId
                FROM Account
                WHERE Id = :newCon.AccountId];

        User communityUser =
                [SELECT Id, UserRole.Name
                FROM User
                WHERE LastName = :PackageUtils.communityOwner];

        acc.OwnerId = communityUser.Id;
        update acc;
        acc =
                [SELECT Id, OwnerId
                FROM Account
                WHERE Id = :newCon.AccountId];

        system.debug(newCon);
        system.debug(UserInfo.getUserId());
        // lastName is a required field on user, but if it isn't specified, we'll default it to the username
        String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, acc.Id, password);
        // create a fake userId for test.
        if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
            userId = 'fakeUserId';
        }
        if (userId != null) {
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(email, password, startUrl);
                if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                    aura.redirect(lgn);
                }
            } else {
                ApexPages.PageReference confirmRef = new PageReference('/');
                if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                    aura.redirect(confirmRef);
                }

            }
        }
        //return null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Database.rollback(sp);
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there a way to keep the account owner as an actual user with a role so I can create a community user?

Comment: Why do you need to update the owner in this flow? Is there any other flow where your account owner is getting set to the current user? Also is there any particular reason to create user this way and just not use the standard `CommunitiesSelfRegController` with necessary modifications?

Comment: It is mostly a copy of the LightningSelfRegisterController that is created, the difference is we are creating our own version of person accounts for contacts and then multiple other accounts for each type of interaction they have with us.  The person account is created in a trigger on contact creation and if that's the account I associate with the user, then I get the error about needing a role for the account owner, which is why I'm trying to change the account owner, but it keeps getting changed back to the user.